# Hi when i try to split a string from a file it take a space as element when i save it in a List Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, machine-learning, tuples

I want to get a data from a file and put in a form of list of tuples like this

```
[('yes', 31, 'good'), ('yes', 31, 'good'), ('yes', 31, 'good')]
```

and my file look like this

[my flie Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLYwc.png)

the problem is when i split it with end line sign (`\n`) it end up putting an element contain a space like the output down

what i did here is splitting it in a list

I want to know why i am getting this space as an element after each string in the list

```
with open('c:\\users\\Ahmed Zaky\\Desktop\\Ahmed\\Master\\TUB\\PyML\\Lecture 1 15 Oktober - 21 Oktober\\Exercise Sheet 1\\health-test.txt','r') as h_test:

D = list()

for t in h_test:
    D.extend([x for x in str.split(t,'\n')])

print(D)
```

output

```
['yes,21,poor', '', 'no,50,good', '', 'no,23,good', '', 'yes,45,poor', '', 'yes,51,good', '', 'no,60,good', '', 'no,15,poor', '', 'no,18,good', '']
```

list of tuples looks like this

```
with open('c:\\users\\Ahmed Zaky\\Desktop\\Ahmed\\Master\\TUB\\PyML\\Lecture 1 15 Oktober - 21 Oktober\\Exercise Sheet 1\\health-test.txt','r') as h_test:

D = list()

for t in h_test:
    D.extend([(x,) for x in str.split(t,'\n')])

print(D)
```

output

```
[('yes,21,poor',), ('',), ('no,50,good',), ('',), ('no,23,good',), ('',), ('yes,45,poor',), ('',), ('yes,51,good',), ('',), ('no,60,good',), ('',), ('no,15,poor',), ('',), ('no,18,good',), ('',)]
```

Comment: instead of `for t in h_test:` do `for t in h_test.read().split("\n"):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `split`ing on the newline, instead `strip` the whitespace from the line. Then `split` the strings you get on the commas, and convert the second value to an `int`:

```
with open(path) as h_test:
    stripped_lines = (line.strip() for line in h_test)
    non_empty_lines = (line for line in stripped_lines if line)
    split_lines = (line.split(',') for line in non_empty_lines)
    D = [(a, int(b), c) for a, b, c in D]
```

This will fail if there are lines that don't have three values, with the second value being an `int`. Depending on your data, you may want to check for that.

Comment: My data has three values for each line the second value must be changed to int